# batch script find and write?

Tags: batch-file, find

i have `log_prof_info_xxx random number xxx.txt`  file (this file creation be last date and time)

this file in line is `h ttp://ipadres:DIGIT(port)/live/path_DIGIT` ( digit is only number but variable)

I want to find this line in that file and save it to an external file ?

example: log_prof_info_809809808.txt content is

```
h ttp://234.56.78:68912/live/osidosi_89797987
```

i tried code and not work :(

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ("findstr "h ttp://234.56.78:[0-9]/live/osidosi_[0-9]" log_prof_info_809809808.txt") do ECHO %%A>>extractedline.txt
```

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to solve a problem stated as ""my code doesn't do what I want it to do" without an indication of sample data or desired outcome. You have shown us one line of data, but no example of how the output should read in the output file.

Answer (score 1):

`for /?` says:

```
FOR /F ["Options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command[Parameter]
```

Note the single quotues `'`.

put the command in single quotes instead of double quotes.
And: you forgot the `*` after `[0-9]` two times (repetition of previous char)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr "h ttp://234.56.78:[0-9]*/live/osidosi_[0-9]*" log_prof_info_809809808.txt') do ECHO %%A>>extractedline.txt
```

(there is a space in `h ttp` - I assume, you are aware of that)

Comment: the problem is not single quotes... problem is process ?
and 
I need a how to write code?

Comment: ah - I missed a `'`. Corrected.

Comment: I get `h ttp://234.56.78:68912/live/osidosi_89797987`

Comment: yes i want to xxx.txt file in search find like this htttp:xxxxxx line extract (stephan u skype ?)

Comment: All three answers (Stephan, foxidrive and Magoo) work fine for me (although I'd prefer Magoos answer, because there is no `for`).

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /r /i /c:"h ttp://234.56.78:[0-9]*/live/osidosi_[0-9]*" log_prof_info_809809808.txt>extractedline.txt
```

worked fine for me - no need for the `FOR` and note that `>` above will creata a new output file containing the one line. This should be changed to `>>` if you want to append to any existing content.

Comment: thanks but extractedline.txt content space not data ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (' findstr "h ttp:\/\/234.56.78:[0-9]\/live\/osidosi_[0-9]" "log_prof_info_809809808.txt" ') do >>extractedline.txt ECHO %%A
```